# Pandas combine multiple related columns into separate groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

I want to convert it to this format:

[image]

What is a suitable technique for doing this in Pandas?

To generate the original dataframe in the first image, you can use the following data.
Generate a dataframe from this data with

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict)


data_dict = {'female_count': {0: 65.0, 1: 13.0, 2: 51.0, 3: 19.0, 4: 53.0, 5: 146.0},
 'jobTitle': {0: 'Associate',
              1: 'Intern',
              2: 'Key Holder',
              3: 'Retail Store Manager',
              4: 'Seasonal Sales Associate',
              5: 'other_jobTitles'},
 'male_count': {0: 44.0, 1: 17.0, 2: 32.0, 3: 6.0, 4: 26.0, 5: 125.0},
 'mean_z_score_female': {0: 0.0,
                         1: 0.0,
                         2: -0.352017669928334,
                         3: 0.08210979257229986,
                         4: -0.10918109741978921,
                         5: 0.23156942728286573},
 'mean_z_score_male': {0: -0.04759213253110343,
                       1: 0.0,
                       2: -0.28872649090170965,
                       3: -0.0027563646918771063,
                       4: 0.0,
                       5: 0.6133138806146933}}
```

Comment: Even with a really big dataframe use a `for` loop is really fast. `for i in range(df.shape[0])` and the create a new dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly simple way to do that using `concat':

```
f = df[["jobTitle", "female_count", "mean_z_score_female"]].rename(columns = {"female_count": "count", 
                                                                          "mean_z_score_female": "mean_z_score"})\
.assign(gender="female")

m = df[["jobTitle", "male_count", "mean_z_score_male"]].rename(columns = {"male_count": "count", 
                                                                          "mean_z_score_male": "mean_z_score"})\
.assign(gender="male")
pd.concat([m, f]).sort_values("jobTitle")
```

The output is:

```
                   jobTitle  count  mean_z_score  gender
0                 Associate   44.0     -0.047592    male
0                 Associate   65.0      0.000000  female
1                    Intern   17.0      0.000000    male
1                    Intern   13.0      0.000000  female
2                Key Holder   32.0     -0.288726    male
2                Key Holder   51.0     -0.352018  female
3      Retail Store Manager    6.0     -0.002756    male
3      Retail Store Manager   19.0      0.082110  female
4  Seasonal Sales Associate   26.0      0.000000    male
4  Seasonal Sales Associate   53.0     -0.109181  female
5           other_jobTitles  125.0      0.613314    male
5           other_jobTitles  146.0      0.231569  female
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for `pd.wide_to_long`, but you first have to rename certain columns, namely `female_count` and `male_count` to `count_female` and `count_male`:

```
df.columns = ["_".join(entry.split("_")[::-1]) 
          if "count" in entry else entry 
          for entry in df]
          ]

print(df.columns)
Index(['count_female', 'jobTitle', 'count_male', 'mean_z_score_female',
   'mean_z_score_male'],
  dtype='object')

print (pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=["count","mean_z_score"],
                       i="jobTitle",j="gender", sep="_", suffix="\w+"))

                                 count  mean_z_score
jobTitle                 gender                     
Associate                female   65.0      0.000000
Intern                   female   13.0      0.000000
Key Holder               female   51.0     -0.352018
Retail Store Manager     female   19.0      0.082110
Seasonal Sales Associate female   53.0     -0.109181
other_jobTitles          female  146.0      0.231569
Associate                male     44.0     -0.047592
Intern                   male     17.0      0.000000
Key Holder               male     32.0     -0.288726
Retail Store Manager     male      6.0     -0.002756
Seasonal Sales Associate male     26.0      0.000000
other_jobTitles          male    125.0      0.613314
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is a very similar answer to Roy2012's that uses `append`:

```
df_new = None
for gender in ['male','female']:
  df_gender = (df[['jobTitle',f'{gender}_count',f'mean_z_score_{gender}']]
               .rename(columns = {f'{gender}_count':'count',
                                  f'mean_z_score_{gender}': 'mean_z_score'}))
  df_gender['gender'] = gender
  df_new = df_gender if df_new is None else df_new.append(df_gender)

df_new = df_new.sort_values(by=['jobTitle','gender'],
                            axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_new)
```

The output is:

```
                    jobTitle  count  mean_z_score  gender
0                  Associate   65.0      0.000000  female
1                  Associate   44.0     -0.047592    male
2                     Intern   13.0      0.000000  female
3                     Intern   17.0      0.000000    male
4                 Key Holder   51.0     -0.352018  female
5                 Key Holder   32.0     -0.288726    male
6       Retail Store Manager   19.0      0.082110  female
7       Retail Store Manager    6.0     -0.002756    male
8   Seasonal Sales Associate   53.0     -0.109181  female
9   Seasonal Sales Associate   26.0      0.000000    male
10           other_jobTitles  146.0      0.231569  female
11           other_jobTitles  125.0      0.613314    male
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using `lreshape`:

```
newdf=pd.lreshape(df,{'count': ['female_count', 'male_count'],'mean_z_score': ['mean_z_score_female', 'mean_z_score_male']})\
        .sort_values('jobTitle')
newdf['genre']=['female','male']*(len(newdf)//2)
```

Output:

```
newdf
                    jobTitle  count  mean_z_score   genre
0                  Associate   65.0      0.000000  female
6                  Associate   44.0     -0.047592    male
1                     Intern   13.0      0.000000  female
7                     Intern   17.0      0.000000    male
2                 Key Holder   51.0     -0.352018  female
8                 Key Holder   32.0     -0.288726    male
3       Retail Store Manager   19.0      0.082110  female
9       Retail Store Manager    6.0     -0.002756    male
4   Seasonal Sales Associate   53.0     -0.109181  female
10  Seasonal Sales Associate   26.0      0.000000    male
5            other_jobTitles  146.0      0.231569  female
11           other_jobTitles  125.0      0.613314    male
```

**Note**: `lreshape` is currently undocumented, and it's possible [it might be removed](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15003#issuecomment-324625271).

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.melt(df,  id_vars=['jobTitle','mean_z_score_female','mean_z_score_male'], 
        value_vars=['female_count', 'male_count'], var_name="gender", value_name='count').melt(
    id_vars=['jobTitle', 'gender','count'],value_vars=['mean_z_score_female','mean_z_score_male'], 
    value_name='mean_z_score').drop('variable', axis=1)
```